# in this case does "put up" indicate "Donate money"?

Tags: grammar

Dressed as a priest (“Father Harris”),
he concocted his most daring ruse.
An astute judge of character,
he would carefully select his mark,
then “find” a wallet stuffed with hundred-dollar bills
(but lacking identification) outside a supermarket
and invite his victim to share his good fortune.
★But first, to establish her credibility,
he stipulated that his victim had to **put up** a sum of money as a testimonial to her probity.

note: Father Harris is scoundrel

I cannot understand sentence of ★ well.
What does **put up** mean?
does it mean **Donate money** ?

**Addittonal**
: The continuation of the above sentence is as follows.

Mrs.Emma Schultz, age 72, tearfully told the police that she had withdrawn $14,000
from her bank and placed it in a shopping bag supplied by the helpful priest,
He told her to hold on to the bag while he went next door to a lawyer's office
to make the sharing of their good fortune legal.

Note: The stage of this story is USA.

I couldn't understand your answer well.
In short, was she going to pay money to lawyer for sharing money of wallet with Father Harris?

Does American people usually use a lawyer to legally own the money they pick up ?
I'm Japanese. this is a little strange.
In Japan, if people want to own the money they pick up,
they own it without telling anyone. We don't have the idea of consulting a lawyer.

Comment: One of Oxford's definitions is 'provide money as backing for an enterprise'. Presumably the victim was asked to pay a sum in the expectation of receiving a much larger sum in return.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20up) has **11a**: contribute, pay // *put up bail money*.

Comment: Legally speaking, "theft by finding" can occur if you take a lost item for yourself without attempting to find the owner, although it would be quite rare to be arrested or prosecuted in such a case. But even if you did want to document your efforts to find the owner to avoid the possibility of such a charge, you wouldn't need to pay a lawyer tens of thousands of dollars to do it.

Comment: Nuclear Hoagie Thanks for the very helpful comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very often when one "puts up" money, it means that one provides money as security. That's the intended sense in which the word is used here. It's like collateral for a loan; the bank takes the collateral if the loan isn't repaid. There's no loan here but the idea is the same - the amount of money is provided to give someone a certain assurance (albeit feigned in this case).

Comment: I could understand it. In this case, put up meant providing money as securiy not donate